# Query Row Count for All Tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need help creating an MSSQL query to pass in every table name to the query below, which returns the number of rows.

This is how I get the row count for a single table:

```
SELECT Total_Rows = SUM(st.row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'TABLE_NAME' AND (index_id < 2)
```

**What is the way to loop this query on all tables, returning an output of each table's name and row count?**

Example output:

```
TableName     RowCount
---------------------
FirstTable    109
SecondTable   2195
ThirdTable    0
```

Comment: detail blog with couple of options : http://sforsuresh.in/getting-rows-count-for-each-table-in-database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use this :

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
 ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

Various other methods include:[here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2537/sql-server-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-database/)

1. sys.partitions Catalog View
2. sys.dm_db_partition_stats Dynamic Management View (DMV)
3. sp_MSforeachtable System Stored Procedure
4. COALESCE() Function

Comment: Perfect! And to show tables in replication, just add this line under WHERE: 
`AND ta.is_replicated = 1`

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'xxx'` and instead `GROUP BY` your object name.

Also, join back to `sys.objects` to get those objects of type `'U'`.

```
SELECT 
  OBJECT_NAME(st.object_id), 
  Total_Rows = SUM(st.row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o 
  ON o.object_id = st.object_id
WHERE (index_id < 2)
  AND o.type = 'U'
GROUP BY st.object_id;
```