# how to find number of empty tables in any schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to query how to find all the empty tables in my schema HR
i already tried with
select * 
from dba_tables
where owner='HR' and num-rows is null;
but i dont know if this is the correct logic or not

Comment: select count(*) from ... will NEVER return NULL, it returns 0 if there are 0 rows

Comment: in this way i have to directly give the table name that is select count(*) from A; but suppose i dont know the table name and there are mnay tables under schema HR and i have to write a query where i can find all the tables which doesnt have any row that is empty table only in the schema hr

Comment: >>>n this way i have to directly give the table name that is select count(*) from A; <<< the key moment is not a table name, but the condition: rowcount IS NEVER NULL, IT CAN BE 0 BUT NOT NULL

Comment: Although you tagged your question with Microsoft SQL Server tags, `DBA_TABLES` is an Oracle view. Please correct the tags as needed for appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5):

When you say 'empty' tables, I take that to mean tables with zero rows.

Using the example in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104870/60085) post as a starting point,

```
WITH TablesAndRowCounts
AS (
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(sc.schema_id) SchemaName
        ,sc.NAME + '.' + ta.NAME TableName
        ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
    FROM sys.tables ta
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
    WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
    GROUP BY sc.schema_id
        ,sc.NAME
        ,ta.NAME
    )
SELECT *
FROM TablesAndRowCounts
WHERE rowcnt = 0
and SchemaName = 'HR'
```